# javascript wait specific amount of time before executing a function

Tags: javascript

is there any way to delay a function in javascript I want to do such thing:

```
function showLabel(){
    document.getElementById(id).show();
    wait(5000); //wait 5 sec
    document.getElementById(id).hide();
}
```

I want to show a label for 5 sec if this function is called, there may be another way to do so.

Note: I can't use jQuery

Comment: Beware there are no built-in `show|hide` methods.

Comment: we hava a custom java web framework and we are writing javascript in it and we have a method as this.componentID.setVisible(true/false) and I am using it, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use `setTimeout`

```
window.setTimeout("javascript function", milliseconds);
```

Read the docs and find out how to do it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

If you want something like sleep then:

```
function sleep(millis, callback) {
    setTimeout(function()
            { callback(); }
    , milliseconds);
}
```

I'd prefer:

```
function doStuff()
{
  //do some things
  setTimeout(continueExecution, 10000) //wait ten seconds before continuing
}

function continueExecution()
{
   //finish doing things after the pause
}
```

Another way using loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// bad implementation
function sleep(milliSeconds){
    var startTime = new Date().getTime(); // get the current time
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds); // hog cpu
}
</script>
```

Comment: setInterval doesn't meant to do it, it call the function again and again in for the given interval.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
function showLabel(){
    document.getElementById(id).show();
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        document.getElementById(id).hide();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Use `setTimeout` for one time task, else `setInterval` for repetitive task.

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout` function in javascript. and clear the time out one the function call over

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function showLabel(){
      document.getElementById(id).show();
        document.getElementById(id).hide();
    }, 5000);
 clearTimeout(timerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(
    function(){ Your_function },  milliseconds
);
```

This calls the function after the given time is up.